# Stata: Replace values of one row based on another if data are missing

Tags: stata

In Stata, I am trying to change the values--both string and numeric--of one row based on the one just above or just below it only if the values are missing. Here are some sample data:

```
input 
str40 id var1 var2 var3 var4 str40 var5_string str40 var6_string
"correctly-spelled" 10 20 . . "random text 1" ""
"misspelled" . . 30 40 "" "random text 2" 
end
```

Essentially, I want my final dataset to look as follows:

```
input
id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5_string var6_string
"correctly-spelled" 10 20 30 40 "random text 1" "random text 2"
end
```

I need a row-specific solution (i.e. avoiding `collapse`), because my (wide) dataset has thousands of labeled variables, and I don't want to lose the labels due to `collapse`. Also, not all of the variables are numeric, and the naming conventions of the variables are not consistent. Accordingly, fixing the spelling of `id` with a simple `replace`, executing a `collapse (firstnm) id var5_string var6_string (mean) var1 var2 var3 var4, by(id)`, or using `var*` for anything won't help. Basically, what happened was one person merged using the "correctly-spelled" `id`, the other person merged using the "misspelled" `id`, and I don't have any of the source files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that the misspelled ID comes right after (or right before) the correctly spelled, you can use `_n±1` to get the previous or following value. For more information on *system variables* see `help _variables`

- If you assume the correct one always comes first, then the second `replace` would be sufficient.
- `mi()` is the abbreviated `missing()` function.
- the second conditions `& !mi(`var'[_n±1])`, are just to make sure that non-missing don't get replaced by missing values, should two valid (but different) ID's come up sequentially. Depending on your data, this further condition might not be necessary.

```
local list_of_vars var1 var2 var3 var4 var5_string var6_string
foreach var of local list_of_vars {
    replace `var' = `var'[_n-1] if mi(`var') & !mi(`var'[_n-1])
    replace `var' = `var'[_n+1] if mi(`var') & !mi(`var'[_n+1])
}
```

```
. list

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                id   var1   var2   var3   var4     var5_string     var6_string |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | correctly-spelled     10     20     30     40   random text 1   random text 2 |
  2. |        misspelled     10     20     30     40   random text 1   random text 2 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then just keep the correct ones. Hopefully you can identify them somehow.

```
// the following is just to be able to identify the correct id's, of course you will have to adapt it so that it matches only the correctly-spelled IDs or you have other way of identifying them :)
gen _ck_corect_id = (id=="correctly-spelled")

keep if _ck_corect_id==1
```

Comment: See https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/  for a broader discussion.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcelo Avila and @Nick Cox! The solution worked perfectly. I just had to select all of the thousands of variables using shift in the variable side pane, and `append` the corrected row back to the original dataset after dropping the two rows in question.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just as side note, you could use `ds` to get all the variables in your dataset. If you want most but not all, you can call `ds var1 var, not` so it will return in `r(varlist)` all variables except `var1` and `var2`. See ` help ds` for more details. In general, whenever you find yourself doing something overly "manualy", there might a easier way of doing it. Not always to figure out how (which command), but might be worth searching or asking :)

Comment: Thanks, @Marcelo Avila! I have been working at least part-time in Stata for the past 10 years now, and I have never heard of `ds`--the learning never stops :) Anyway, glad to have Stack Overflow and folks like you to inform me about these shortcuts. I try to return the favor and answer questions myself, too, when I get a chance.

Comment: Late to this party, but my contribution was adding the `not` option and some others to `ds`. Thanks for the thanks.